create columns dynamically depending on string structure in Python
To give background on my project, comparing two documents which has nested JSON structure using deepDiff in python. During comparison, if values of a field are changed, those are written to a DataFrame for analysis.
Example data change:
"values_changed": {
    "root['prod1']['p_col']['c_col']": {
        "new_value": -2.866711109999983,
        "old_value": -2.75
    },
    "root['prod1']['p_col23']": {
        "new_value": 1,
        "old_value": 54
    },
    "root['prod1']['p_col']['c_col2']['c_col5']": {
        "new_value": 1.678,
        "old_value": 5.12
    }
}

Current output:



product
field
new_value
old_value




prod
p_col
-2.866
-2.75


prod
p_col23
1
54


prod
p_col
1.678
5.12



I am using string pattern to read till root['prod1']['p_col'], adding to another dict further converted to pandas dataframe 
k = """root['prod1']['p_col']['c_col']"""
field = k[k.find("['",8)+1:k.find("']",-1)].split("'")[1::2][0]

but want to dynamically add new column on existence of nested field in string
Required output:



product
parent-field
field
field
new_value
old_value




prod
p_col
c_col

-2.866
-2.75


prod
p_col23


1
54


prod
p_col
c_col2
c_col5
1.678
5.12




And what if you find another "nested field"? What do you want to call the new column? Why not store a list of strings in just one column?

Your data is incomplete (missing closing }) and malformed. Please include actually valid data, that we can use to test any answer, covering all your use cases. Please read: [mre]

have done the changes to question

Can you clarify if there are always 4 levels in the string? If not, how do you chose the names?

Your data is still invalid. It's a key and a dictionary, so I presume the whole thing should be a dictionary. But someone here thinks it should be a string. Please make you data something we can actually use in a python script.

You could convert the json to dictionary, then extractall the names from the strings in the index:
import json

s = '''"values_changed": {
    "root['prod1']['p_col']['c_col']": {
        "new_value": -2.866711109999983,
        "old_value": -2.75
    },
    "root['prod1']['p_col23']": {
        "new_value": 1,
        "old_value": 54
    },
    "root['prod1']['p_col']['c_col2']['c_col5']": {
        "new_value": 1.678,
        "old_value": 5.12
    }
}'''

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.loads(f'{{{s}}}')['values_changed'],
                            orient='index')

# mapper to name the columns
# all other levels will default to "field"
names = {0: 'product', 1: 'parent-field'}

df = (df.index.str.extractall("\['(\w+)'\]")[0].unstack('match')
        .rename(columns=lambda x: names.get(x, 'field')) # optional
        .join(df.reset_index(drop=True))
     )

If values_changed is already a dictionary, then the first step should be: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values_changed, orient='index')
Output:
  product parent-field   field   field  new_value  old_value
0   prod1        p_col   c_col     NaN  -2.866711      -2.75
1   prod1      p_col23     NaN     NaN   1.000000      54.00
2   prod1        p_col  c_col2  c_col5   1.678000       5.12


Seems like there is a correlation between the keys/values of the changed values and the left/right part of your expected dataframe. If so, my proposition would be to findall the fields, build a DataFrame for both sides and join them :
import re, json

obj = json.loads(inp.removeprefix('"values_changed": '))
# or, obj = inp["values_changed"] if `inp` is a valid dict

ldf = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        re.findall(r"([^[\]']+)", k)[1:] for k in obj.keys()
    ], columns=["product", "parent-field", "field", "field"],
)

rdf = pd.DataFrame(obj.values())

out = ldf.join(rdf)
Output :
  product parent-field   field   field  new_value  old_value
0   prod1        p_col   c_col    None  -2.866711      -2.75
1   prod1      p_col23    None    None   1.000000      54.00
2   prod1        p_col  c_col2  c_col5   1.678000       5.12


So, one way to achieve this is the following, but the solution I provide works only if you json has the structure that you presented. If it differs, you'll need to adapt it to your new layout:
import pandas as pd

values_changed = {
    "root['prod1']['p_col']['c_col']": {
        "new_value": -2.866711109999983,
        "old_value": -2.75
    },
    "root['prod1']['p_col23']": {
        "new_value": 1,
        "old_value": 54
    },
    "root['prod1']['p_col']['c_col2']['c_col5']": {
        "new_value": 1.678,
        "old_value": 5.12
    }
}

def process_change(key, change):
    parts = [part for part in key.split("']['") if part]
    
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace("root['", "")
    parts[-1] = parts[-1].replace("']", "")
    
    new_value = change['new_value']
    old_value = change['old_value']
    
    return parts, new_value, old_value

max_depth = 0
processed_changes = []
for key, change in values_changed.items():
    parts, new_value, old_value = process_change(key, change)
    max_depth = max(max_depth, len(parts))
    processed_changes.append((parts, new_value, old_value))

rows = []
for parts, new_value, old_value in processed_changes:
    field_parts = parts[1:] + [''] * (max_depth - len(parts))
    row = [parts[0]] + field_parts + [new_value, old_value]
    rows.append(row)

column_names = ['product'] + [f'field_{i}' for i in range(1, max_depth)] + ['new_value', 'old_value']

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=column_names)
df = df.rename(columns={'field_1': 'parent-field', 'field_2': 'child-field', 'field_3': 'grandchild-field})
print(df)


which will give you
  product parent-field child-field grandchild-field  new_value  old_value
0   prod1        p_col       c_col                   -2.866711      -2.75
1   prod1      p_col23                                1.000000      54.00
2   prod1        p_col      c_col2           c_col5   1.678000       5.12

